# JAVA How do I read an input from the user containing math operators and numbers in one expression?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment that asks me to create a Basic calculator, by taking an input from the user in one expressions as in "4 - 1" or "5 + 3", and I need to check each number(1-9) and the operator (+,-,*,/) to see whether it is applicable. My question is how do I check whether the expression has a valid operator and spaces in between numbers and operator? (I'm a beginner in Java, and thank you in advance to whoever answers)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not entirely sure where you are stuck, this example expression may be your best friend:

```
    String exampleString = "Example String";
    char exampleChar = example.charAt(3);
```

This statement is true:

```
    exampleChar == 'm'
```

**EDIT FOR ADDITIONS**

To read the user input, you would need to read different types of characters. To read a number using the Scanner class, you would use **.nextInt()** or **.nextDouble()** to check for spaces and symbols, using **.next()** only reads till the next break. Please elaborate where you are getting stuck/where we can be more specific :)